# Puppetmaster broken after git repo trashed, then restored with fresh clone

Tags: git, activerecord, puppet

I recently had to create a fresh clone of my git repo on a puppet master 3.0.0 server after having mangled the working local git repo. Git says the repo is clean and up-to-date but when puppet clients try to connect I'm seeing they fail.

The errors in puppetmaster.log look like this:

```
Fri Sep 27 14:14:50 +0000 2013 Puppet (err): Could not autoload puppet/indirector/node/active_record: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord
Fri Sep 27 14:14:50 +0000 2013 Puppet (err): Could not autoload puppet/indirector/node/active_record: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord
Fri Sep 27 14:14:50 +0000 2013 //baba.blacksheep.com/Puppet (err): Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not autoload puppet/indirector/node/active_record: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord
```

Comment: gem list:
f5-icontrol (10.2.0.2)
httpclient (2.3.3)
json (1.4.6)

Comment: This puppet master is using a MySql back end.